# Boundary of a simply-connected domain

Tags: general-topology

Is the boundary of a simply-connected bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ connected?

The $n=1$ case is clearly false. The $n=2$ case is true from the Riemann mapping theorem. What about when $n\geq 3$?

Comment: Think about a 3-dimensional spherical shell.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Of course, thanks. What would be a higher dimensional version of the statement then? Vanishing homology groups of order up to $n-1$ of the $n$-dimensinal domain to guarantee connectedness of its boundary?

Comment: Vanishing in degree $n-1$ would suffice. You can deduce this from the Alexander duality.